# Used to Add a fragment A to fragment B and go back with the result to fragment A

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am using this code with a onActivityResult. For the fragmentB and go back to the fragmentA with the result-code. This is fine but I need some improvement.

```
  getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
                            getTargetRequestCode(),
                            Activity.RESULT_OK,
                            new Intent().putExtras(bundle)


fragmentA.(Add a fragmentB)
 searchBankListFragment.setTargetFragment(WalletToBankFragment.this, 0);

FragmentA.(get back to the result) 

      @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (Common.nonNull(data)) {
                   selectedbankMap = (BankMapping) data.getSerializableExtra(SearchBankListFragment.bank`enter code here`List);
                    if (Common.nonNull(bankMapping))
                        tvBankName.setText(selectedbankMap.getBankName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is working final, but I need some improvement.

Comment: What improvement you need?

Comment: I need some Standardisation in my code.

Comment: in this link to communication in between a one activity  to attached the two fragment. but now in my case I have a  different activity with multiple fragment are attached. please explain ??